Canonical module of a squarefree monomial ideal
I am trying to understand Theorem 4 from the paper by Grabe (The canonical module of a Stanley-Reisner ring, https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(84)90066-8). This theorem describes the canonical module of the coordinate ring of a squarefree monomial ideal. However, I am struggling with the definitions provided in Section 2.1, especially because the notations for homological tools are not entirely standard. Specifically, I am unclear about the following notations:
$$H^i_m(R),\ \varinjlim_t H^i(x^t, R),\ H^i(\varinjlim_t (-) ) $$
These definitions seem to reference the book "Herzog and Kunz, Der kanonische Modul eines Cohen-Macaulay-Rings, Lecture Notes in Mathematics No. 238, Springer-Verlag, 1971". Unfortunately, this book is in German, which I do not understand.

Can someone familiar with these tools provide a detailed explanation of these notations or point me to a reference where they are explained thoroughly?


Additionally, I am trying to interpret Theorem 4 in a concrete example. Consider the squarefree monomial ideal
$$
I = (x_1x_2, x_2x_3, x_3x_4, x_1x_5, x_2x_6, x_3x_7, x_4x_8)
$$
in $R = K[x_1, \dots, x_8]$, where $K$ is a field. This ideal $I$ is the edge ideal of a whisker graph of a tree (see Theorem 2.4 in https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02568497}), so $R/I$ is Cohen-Macaulay.
I used the Macaulay2 package TestIdeals and the function canonicalIdeal to compute the ideal isomorphic to the canonical module. Here is the code and output:
i1 : loadPackage "TestIdeals"

o1 = TestIdeals

o1 : Package

i2 : R = QQ[x_1..x_8]

o2 = R

o2 : PolynomialRing

i3 : I = ideal(x_1*x_2, x_2*x_3, x_3*x_4, x_1*x_5, x_2*x_6, x_3*x_7, x_4*x_8)

o3 = ideal (x_1*x_2, x_2*x_3, x_3*x_4, x_1*x_5, x_2*x_6, x_3*x_7, x_4*x_8)

o3 : Ideal of R

i4 : S = R/I

o4 = S

o4 : QuotientRing

i5 : canonicalIdeal S

o5 = ideal (x_6*x_8, x_6*x_7, x_5*x_7)

o5 : Ideal of S

The output is the ideal $(x_6x_8, x_6x_7, x_5x_7)$ in $S = R/I$.

My question is: how can this output be interpreted in light of Theorem 4 of Grabe's article? Specifically, how does this relate to the structure of the canonical module as described in the theorem?


Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!
